# не с причастиями

Tags: причастия

Здравствуйте! Поясните, пожалуйста, почему в словосочетании *временно неработающий* не с причастием пишется слитно,  ведь согласно правилу наличие зависимого слова влечет раздельное написание не с причастием. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гражданин NN,  временно неработающий - это социальный статус, здесь неработающий - это причастие, перешедшее  в существительное.

Answer (score 3):

Это *субстантивированное имя существительное*, которое образовалось путём перехода из одной части речи (причастие) в другую. Однако, если это слово является причастием и не утрачивает значение действия, писать нужно раздельно.

*Я временно неработающий* (=безработный). 
*Людей, временно не работающих (значение действия налицо), мы не кормим*.